# Module Plugin on PyroCMS is not loading

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have created a module that works on the administrator and public side. On the public side, I want to have a plugin for certain parts which I can put into the pages.

I have done this but it doesn't load after putting in {pyro:properties:rental}

Here is the code in /addons/modules/properties/plugin.php.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Plugin_Properties extends Plugin
{
function rental()
{           
        $rentalForm = '<div class="search_full">
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_12">
                <h1>Rental Search</h1>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="grid_4">
                <h2 class="liberationtext">Choose your destination</h2>

                <label for="region">Region</label>

            </div>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>';
    return $rentalForm;
    }
}
```

The module is called properties and the plugin just returns some HTML to display.

When I look at the log, it says ERROR - 2011-05-18 13:53:57 --> Unable to load: properties

I made this into a plugin (in the plugins folder) and it worked fine when I called it. I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be good.

Comment: are you creating a module or a plugin? if you are creating a new moudule you have to create it inside module folder.

Comment: i beleive you should upload it to addons/plugins/

Comment: I'm creating a module which has a plugin for the front end. From the documentation, it says you can either do it in a module or as its own standalone plugin. I can get it to work in the plugins folder but I'd rather have it as a module...

Comment: according to your above requirement it would be better if you create a different module.

Comment: In what way? Different name? I have got around the issue by using a plugin in the plugin folder and using the module to do the processing side of it.

Answer (score 1):

I still a beginner in pyrocms but all seems correct implementing this modular plugin.

- pyro tag {pyro:properties:rental} **it's OK**
- file container /addons/modules/properties/plugin.php. **it's OK**
- Code in plugin file  **it's OK**

So the problem must be triggered in another part.

A very useful answer that mention modular plugins in [Pyrocms module or widget or plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935489/pyrocms-module-or-widget-or-plugin/4940785#4940785)

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
{{properties:rental}}
{{/properties:rental}}
```

you will see the `search_full` div output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
{{properties:rental}}
```

you don't need to close it

```
{{/properties:rental}}
```

[Pyrocms developing-plugins](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/addons/developing-plugins)